# Spring-Cloud on Weblogic 12.1.2

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, weblogic12c, spring-cloud-netflix

We have developed Spring-boot microservices with **NetFlix OSS/Spring-cloud**. In the development environment, we are running with embedded tomcat, it works well.

Now I'm trying to deploy on Weblogic 12.1.2, I'm able to deploy service registry and API-Gateway inside two different managed servers. But When I open Eureka server page, API-Gateway is not registered with the Service Registry.

**Service-Registry** application.yml

```
spring:
    application:
        name: service-registry
server:
    port: 61001 

eureka:
    client:
        register-with-eureka: false
        fetch-registry: false
```

**api-gateway** application.yml

```
spring:
    application:
        name: api-gateway

    cloud:
      loadbalancer:
        retry: 
          enabled: true
    # Ribbon - Client side load balancer
ribbon:
  ReadTimeout : 60000
  ConnectTimeout: 60000


server:
    port: 61002
    context-path: /nasw

eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://<ipAdr>:61001/eureka/
   # instance:
#        instanceId: 

### Zuul - Router/Filter/Reverse Proxy
zuul:
    ignoredServices: '*'
    host:
      connect-timeout-millis: 100000
      socket-timeout-millis: 600000
    routes:
        network-planning: "**/network-planning/**"
        network-schemagen: "**/network-schemagen/**"
        network-verification: "**/network-verification/**"
        nw-netgeoview-nw-tracer: "**/nw-netgeoview-nw-tracer/**"



### Hystrix -  Circuit Breaker/Fault&Latency Tolerant
hystrix:
    command:
        default:
            execution:
              isolation:
                thread:
                  timeoutInMilliseconds: 600000
              timeout: 
                enabled: false
                isolation:
                    strategy: SEMAPHORE
```

Service registry home page
[image]

Could you please help me with following queries?

1. Is it possible to deploy Spring-Cloud on Weblogic 12.1.2?
2. Is it a correct way to deploy each microservice in a separate managed server?
3. If Yes, Am I missing any configuration so that api-gateway can register with service-registry?

Comment: Any logs from registering applications?

Comment: @spencergibb No, There are no logs generated related to registering

Comment: I'm not sure how I can help with out any more information.

Comment: @spencergibb First thing is I'm not sure whether we can deploy spring-cloud on WebLogic? And If yes, how we can deploy? Any links or any docs?

Comment: We have nothing specific for weblogic.

Comment: @NagaveerGowda  did you manage to figure this out? There seems to be major issues with different jersey versions in eureke and weblogic causing havoc.